# Reference. Recession cone and max-min of a function.

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, reference-works

I am looking for some bibliographic references where I can find a relationship between recession cone of a set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and the minimum / maximum of a  function $f\colon U\to\mathbb{R}^n$.  For example "if $a\in U$ is min of $f$ then $U_\infty$ is ..."

Comment: This question is pretty unclear/broad. Is there any relation between $f$ and $U$?

Comment: @gerw this is exactly the question, a relation for a recession cone and a convex function. I found something which envolves the recession of the level sets for a convex, closed f.